# How to send data to show in html while loading a page in phonegap

Tags: cordova

Suppose I've two pages in my site index.html and about.html in phonegap. Now I want to load some data while going to about.html from index.html using jQuery or jQueryMobile. I've seen two methods $.mobile.loadPage() and $.mobile.changePage() can carry data to the page concern.

Now if I send some data while changing the page from index.html to about.html, how to receive those data and show them in about.html?

I'm using this  tag to go to about.html

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
onclick="loadTest();" >Test</a>
```

and the code for loadTest() is

```
function loadTest() {
        var name = "Rafiul Sabbir";
    var email = "iamrafiul@gmail.com";
    $.mobile.changePage( "about.html", {
        type: "post",
        data: {name: name, email: email},
    });     
}
```

My main content of the body part of about.html is as follows

```
<div data-role="content">
    <h3>Data Goes here</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <div id="name" class="name">
        </div>
         </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <div id="email" class="email">
        /div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Now how can I recieve/get the name and email I've send from index.html using loadTest() method and show it in about.html

Please help me. I'm in deep trouble. If there is any other way than this, let me know it too!! Anything that works is good enough for me.